# MySQL split a column out with ID

Tags: mysql, split

I'm looking to split one of my MySQL columns out as it is made of words separated via , (commas). I need to split the data on the (,)  and also collect the corresponding ID so I can place it into anther table. What the easiest way to go about this.

eg **From:** Current

```
frog -- Table
ID   common_name 
1    Yellow-spotted Tree Frog, Yellow-spotted Bell Frog
```

**To:**

```
common_name_frog  -- Table
Frog_id Common_name
1       Yellow-spotted Tree Frog
1       Yellow-spotted Bell Frog
```

Comment: The easiest way is to store one (ID, common name) entry per row rather than have a comma-separated list in a column. You're fighting with your dbms rather than using it as a relational db.

Comment: Correct that's what I'm looking to do. It was a downloaded Taxonomy and had this column already in it but I didn't want to have to go through 7k records by hand. The split is so I can create a 2nd table.

Comment: Oh well, fair enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to export the data and use another tool.  If the strings are not too long, you can do something like this:

```
create table common_name_frog as
    select f.id,
           substring_index(substring_index(common_name, ', ', n.n), ', ', -1) as Common_name
    from (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3) n join
         frog f
         on n.n <= length(common_name) - length(replace(common_name, ',', '')) + 1;
```

Comment: Is it possible to drop out null results? as there are some gaps in the data.

Comment: DELETE FROM common_name_frog WHERE common_name IS NULL; or DELETE FROM common_name_frog WHERE common_name ='';

Comment: You could add `having Comon_Name is not null` to the query.  This uses a MySQL extension for the `having` clause